# CentOS 7.6 - yum update error "Cannot find a valid baseurl for repos: addons/7"

Tags: centos, yum

When I am trying to do `yum update`, I got the following error message.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository updates is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch= error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:4178:5:200::10: Network is unreachable

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: addons/7
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you do `curl http://mirrorlist.centos.org` and see if you get a valid HTML response? If not, you'll need to the check the internet connectivity on this system.

Comment: I tried `curl http://mirrorlist.centos.org` and I got a empty response.

Comment: But I could get a valid response when I do `ping mirrorlist.centos.org`. What internet connectivity problem would it be?

Comment: A firewall might be interfering with your connection. Please check this: https://serverfault.com/a/177407

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Somehow my firewall is blocking port 80 outbound, meanwhile allows port 443 outbound. So it is solved by changing the firewall setting.

Comment: Good to know :-) . Consider adding an answer here with the changes you have done, so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 2):

For those who had similar problem, I had solved the problem by the following steps.

1. Go to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` and change `ONBOOT=yes`
2. Add http to firewall by `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http`
3. Restart the firewall `firewall-cmd --reload`
4. Restart the network `service network restart`

And then the problems go away.